# Symfony 1.4: Secure dev-environment on production server

Tags: php, symfony1, authorization, symfony-1.4, development-environment

I want to provide a dev-environment on the production server for my Symfony 1.4 projects. Reasons:

- Allows me to get details of errors, etc.
- It happens very often that I get different output on the prod-server and on my private development server. This is due to different server configuration, php extensions and available data.
- Sometimes my client wants to see small changes quickly. I don't want to clear the cache until changes are available
- The most important point: I want to be dead certain that no "cache-magic" is going on when problems occur on the production server.

A bad idea would be to make /frontend_dev.php accessible for everyone.

Also, I can't use sfGuard, since the dev-environment must be accessible regardless of whether I'm logged in or not.

I'm running my projects on Apache 2. Maybe there is a solution using htaccess.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `frontend_dev.php` just use [HTTP authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) to protect the file

Or in `.htaccess` (or vhost file) you can do this to protect your `frontend_dev.php` script:

```
<FilesMatch "frontend_dev.php">
   AuthName "Restricted file"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /path/to/file/.htpasswd
   require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

EDIT: And if you're using the command `symfony project:deploy production --go` to deploy your project into production, be sure to change the `rsync_exclude.txt` file so it copies over the `frontend_dev.php` file too.

Answer (score 1):

You might have multiple _dev, _cache, _test environments so it's a good idea to make them accessible via a subdomain (verysecret.x.com) and the Restriction posted by @Flukey.